# Is it there a way to create a video playout system? (Preferably in Linux)

Tags: video, playback, broadcasting, preview

I am facing a situation caused by the need to start broadcasting in High Definition and there are a few Digital Automation/Playout Suppliers that offer excellent solutions such as Fission, Miranda, Black Magic, Tricaster and a few other.

My question is related to the possibility to use a different system, preferably (but not limited to) in a Linux based system.

I am currently using a NLES Sony Vegas 8.0 timeline in order to use the preview's output in the secondary monitor (via GPU) for sending such video to an analog video converter and this way drop the signal to my video switcher, after which I can route both the audio and the video to the transmission block.

I would appreciate a lot if somebody tell me if is it there a way to keep my current workflow by adding a digital video card to my computer in order to Sony Vegas drop the video signals to the proper outputs.

Additionally, if the solution involves linux, I would really appreciate if somebody provides the details of such solution. I have tested many free and open source software in Linux (Ubuntu) but they are far from my needs yet. It does not matter if the software is paid, free or open source.

BTW: I am planning to include Tricaster 8000 in my production lane, just to be considered.

Thanks in advance.